# Getting nullpointerexception, why

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Declared:

```
private Man[] man;
```

This is the initialization:

```
Man[] man = new Man[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        man[i] = new Man();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                man[i].eatThis(table.foods[table.topFood-1]);
                table.topFood--;
            }
    }
```

Want to print this:

```
System.out.println(getMan(0));
```

which goes to:

```
public Man getMan(int k){
 return man[k];
}
```

but I receive NullPointerException. Why? While:

```
System.out.println(man[0]);
```

works just fine.

It returns:

```
Man = (bread, meat, cheese)
```

Here's the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ManRunning.getMan(ManRunning.java:80)
at ManRunning.newGame(ManRunning.java:133)
at ManRunning.<init>(ManRunning.java:57)
at RunDevilRun.main(RunDevilRun.java:9)
```

Comment: That happens when you switch them at the same place?

Comment: Is the array man[] still in scope in this function?

Comment: Any shadowing issues a possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are actually *shadowing* the class member `man` with a local variable `man`. At your initialization

```
Man[] man = new Man[1];
```

This declares a new variable.  Local variables with the same name as class members are allowed, and they  will hide (aka shadow) the class level variable.  So, while it looks like you are initializing `man`, you are in fact initializing a local array and not touching the one in your class.  To just initialize it and not declare a new one, you want to say just:

```
man = new Man[1];
```

Comment: ...and of course the shadowing was not as obvious as hindsight reveals it is. +1